# using React render in Autodesk ForgeViewer v7.+

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

How use **render** and **return** from React library in Forge Extensions, exp. here: 
(I want to use *WidgetContainer* Component as sidebar)
[Viewing.Extension.IoT.2](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/89e2e0af1d87e3b948cb66bc88f54140c6e8a0e8/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.IoT.2/Viewing.Extension.IoT.2.js#L644)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `ReactDOM` to render the component in your Viewer extension like below:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
//...
class YourExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {

//...
load(){
ReactDOM.render(<ReflexElement
              propagateDimensions
              renderOnResize
              minSize={101}
              flex={0.4}
            >
              <IoTGraphContainer
                item={state.activeItem}
              />
            </ReflexElement>
        }
      </ReflexContainer>, container)

return true
}

//...

}
```

See a case in point [here](https://github.com/dukedhx/viewer-iot-react-feathersjs/blob/master/src/client/iconExtension.js)

Comment: Thanks. How can I use _WidgetContainer_? I want to use Sidebar (left od right) for Charts such as _Viewing.Extension.IoT.2_. I have done this before with react layout split and Redux...

Comment: the same way as it's used in the sample as we'd be rendering directly from the extension - see [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Extensions/Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.PlantFactory/Viewing.Extension.PlantFactory.js) for an example

Comment: Thank you for the link. but where is _reflex container, element, splitter_ defined?

Comment: they are packaged separately [here](http://github.com/leefsmp/Re-Flex) - you can do a search in the RCDB repo to follow them up ... but i'd recommend against using them in your own project if the benefits start to outweigh the effort required to integrate ... RCDB is supposed/meant to be showcase of samples (that uses these React components solely to serve its purposes) rather than starting point to get going with its React components ... you'd probably be better of coming up with your own design that you're more comfortable with as Viewer can work with almost anything HTML/CSS/JS...

Comment: yes I have tested the package _Re-F|ex_ local but I was wondering to know how works RCDB with reflex, thanks.